# Need help with NSXMLPARSER!

Tags: iphone, xml, nsxmlparser

```
<webservicecep>
<quantidade>2</quantidade>

<retorno>
<cep>31010330</cep>
<uf>MG</uf>
<cidade>Belo Horizonte</cidade>
<bairro>Santa Teresa</bairro>
<tipo_logradouro>Rua</tipo_logradouro>
<logradouro>Paraisópolis</logradouro>
<resultado>1</resultado>
<resultado_txt>sucesso. logradouro encontrado local</resultado_txt>
<limite_buscas>5</limite_buscas>
<ibge_uf>31</ibge_uf>
<ibge_municipio>310620</ibge_municipio>
<ibge_municipio_verificador>3106200</ibge_municipio_verificador>
</retorno>

<retorno>
<cep>31010475</cep>
<uf>MG</uf>
<cidade>Belo Horizonte</cidade>
<bairro>Santa Teresa</bairro>
<tipo_logradouro>Rua</tipo_logradouro>
<logradouro>Paraisópolis</logradouro>
<resultado>1</resultado>
<resultado_txt>sucesso. logradouro encontrado local</resultado_txt>
<limite_buscas>5</limite_buscas>
<ibge_uf>31</ibge_uf>
<ibge_municipio>310620</ibge_municipio>
<ibge_municipio_verificador>3106200</ibge_municipio_verificador>
</retorno>

</webservicecep>
```

I need to parser this XML usuing NSXMLPARSER.

I already have a class mapping the "retorno" object.

Can anyone give an example on how to parser the data in the "retorno" object into an NSMutableArray?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Well, no one is going to write a complete code for you. Please read about Event Driven Parsing, and NSXMLParser (there're plenty of tutorials that are findable with google)

Comment: Thanx for nothing... I just wanted a direction... Anyway, I already got it!